# Log when a row is deleted from a given table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-table that's accessed from different APIs. I would like to log when any rows are deleted from this table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use a simple trigger, something like;

```
CREATE TRIGGER data_delete BEFORE DELETE ON data FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log(logmessage) VALUES (CONCAT('Delete of value ', OLD.id));
END
```

[A simple SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf6f9/1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You have to use [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for this purpose. Using triggers you can save the data, time and other information after the delete occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and based my solution on Joachim Isaksson's solution, but had to add a DELIMITER line before and after.

```
CREATE TABLE log_user_table (old_user_id VARCHAR(20), old_user_email VARCHAR(20), when_deleted DATE);
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER user_delete BEFORE DELETE ON user FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO log_user_table(old_user_id,old_user_email,when_deleted) VALUES (OLD.id,OLD.email,NOW());
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```